# Checkboxes not selecting sheets for PDF generation

Tags: arrays, vba, checkbox, pdf-generation

I have a an Active X Button that when clicked brings up a Userform with checkboxes for each sheet in my workbook. What I am trying to do is allow the user to select which sheets they want to generate into a PDF. Currently, regardless of what checkboxes are selected once the user hits the enter button that generates the PDF, all the sheets in the workbook are included in the PDF not what was selected and the sub will not end automatically, I have to automatically go into the VBA and hit the stop button. So please if you could let me know what I am doing wrong with my code and why the checkboxes are not selecting the sheets I want to be generated into a PDF. Thanks in advance for all help!

```
Private Sub chbxEnter_Click()

Dim PDFsheets As String
Dim s As Worksheet
PDFsheets = "Approval Form,Business Plan,Deal Worksheet,All Manager Deal Recap,Deal Recap,MEC Dealership Profile,Loyal,Mid Loyal,Non Loyal,Projected Incentive Report,MEC"
ary = Split(PDFsheets, ",")

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    PDFsheets = "Approval Form"
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        If PDFsheets = "" Then
        PDFsheets = "Business Plan"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Business Plan"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        If PDFsheets = "" Then
        PDFsheets = "Deal Worksheet"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Deal Worksheet"
    End If
    End If


    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "Deal Recap"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Deal Recap"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "All Manager Deal Recap"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",All Manager Deal Recap"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox6.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "MEC Dealership Profile"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",MEC Dealership Profile"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox7.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "Loyal"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Loyal"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox8.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "Mid Loyal"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Mid Loyal"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox9.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "Non Loyal"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Non Loyal"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox10.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "Projected Incentive Report"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Projected Incentive Report"
    End If
    End If

    If CheckBox11.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
       PDFsheets = "MEC"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",MEC"
    End If
    End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(1).Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think this should do what you need.  A lot of repeated logic was factored out into a separate sub.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub chbxEnter_Click()

    Dim pdfSheets As String

    pdfSheets = ""

    AddASheet CheckBox1, pdfSheets, "Approval Form"
    AddASheet CheckBox2, pdfSheets, "Business Plan"
    AddASheet CheckBox3, pdfSheets, "Deal Worksheet"
    AddASheet CheckBox4, pdfSheets, "Deal Recap"
    AddASheet CheckBox5, pdfSheets, "All Manager Deal Recap"
    AddASheet CheckBox6, pdfSheets, "MEC Dealership Profile"
    AddASheet CheckBox7, pdfSheets, "Loyal"
    AddASheet CheckBox8, pdfSheets, "Mid Loyal"
    AddASheet CheckBox9, pdfSheets, "Non Loyal"
    AddASheet CheckBox10, pdfSheets, "Projected Incentive Report"
    AddASheet CheckBox11, pdfSheets, "MEC"


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Split(pdfSheets, ",")).Select
      ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

     ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(1).Select
End Sub

'utility: add a sheet name if a checkbox is checked
Sub AddASheet(cb, ByRef pdfSheets As String, shtName As String)
    If cb.Value Then
        pdfSheets = pdfSheets & IIf(Len(pdfSheets) > 0, ",", "") & shtName
    End If
End Sub
```